# SQL Server : cannot perform an aggregate function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Can someone explain me why this works:

```
select val1, val2, 
   count(case when table2.someID in (1, 2, 3, 48967, 123456) then table2.someId end) as val3
from table1
join table2 on table1.someId = table2.someId
where blabla
group by val1, val2
order by val1
```

but this query here:

```
select val1, val2, 
   count(case when table2.someID in (Select someId from table567) then table2.someId end) as val3
from table1
join table2 on table1.someId = table2.someId
where blabla
group by val1, val2
order by val1
```

gives error:

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an
>   aggregate or a subquery.

(`someId` is PK in `table2`)

Comment: the error is kinda self-explanatory, you cannot perform an aggregate function ( count(...) ) on an expression containing a subquery ( your "select someid .." )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get around this by using a left join rather than a subquery.

```
select  val1, 
        val2, 
        count(table567.someID) as val3
from    table1
        join table2 on table1.someId = table2.someId
        left join table567 on table2.someID = table567.someID
where blabla
group by val1, val2
order by val1
```

Comment: or even just `count(table567.someID)`.

Comment: @AndriyM Good spot. Edited answer.

Comment: the query is slower a bit but I accept the answer anyway, thanks for the help :)

Comment: @a-MEE how can the query that works be slower than the query that doesn't run and returns an error?

Answer (score 4):

Well, if it "*Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing (...) subquery*" then reason is simple: in second query you have subquery (`Select someId from table567`) in aggregate function `count` and in first you don't.